# ng-repeat through object with value as an array angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object with key value pairs that looks like this. You will see that the key has an array as its value.

```
$scope.testObj = {

   "London":[
         {"id":1,"city":"London","country":"GB","name":"Test1"},
         {"id":4,"city":"London","country":"GB","name":"Test2"}
   ],

   "Los Angeles":[
       {"id":8,"city":"LA","country":"US","name":"Test3"}
   ]

}
```

I want to display the name next to the city in the front end using angular. To do this I have tried many approaches, and used track by $index, but cannot figure out how to get this working.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in jobsByCity track by $index">
    {{key}}:{{val[$index].name}}
</div>
```

I have looked at this approach too, nesting ng-repeat

```
 <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in testCity">
    {{key}}
    <div ng-repeat="test in val[$index].name">
       {{test}}
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I guess you have to use nested ng-repeats

Comment: @k102 i think you are probably right, i have attempted this above. please see updated question

Comment: London and Los Angeles also need quotes.

Comment: @Rob apologies, they do, just for the purpose of the question I forgot to add them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use another `ng-repeat` to iterate over the value:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in jobsByCity">
    <div ng-repeat="subValue in val track by $index">
        {{key}}:{{subValue.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Also note that your `Los Angeles` property needs to be in quotes, otherwise it isn't valid javascript.

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/303ggjkk/)